# ListIterator - not working as expected (Kotlin)

Tags: java, list, kotlin, iterator

Is this the expected behaviour of a list iterator ?
The comments are what I was expected to be
[image]

Comment: From the documentation: *A ListIterator has **no** current element; its cursor position always lies between the element that would be returned by a call to `previous()` and the element that would be returned by a call to `next()`*, so yes, the shown behaviour is to be expected

Comment: Kotlin documentation is not that specific : https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list-iterator/
but I've found the answer here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html

Thank you @Lino

Comment: Please post code as text, images cannot be copied or read by users with screenreaders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the `a b b b c` output is the expected behavior.

Java's [`ListIterator.previous()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous--) documentation explicitly says:

> Note that alternating calls to `next` and `previous` will return the **same** element repeatedly.

The `previous()` call is supposed to return `b`. The main documentation for [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) explains how it works, so read that to learn why.

The code is working as designed.